# getter and setter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, properties, getter-setter

I am still learning about getter and setter here. If I used field in getter and setter It still not working:

```
class Cat(private val name: String) {

    var sleep: Boolean = false

    fun get() = println("Function getter is called")

    fun set() = println("Function setter is called")

    fun toSleep() {
        if (sleep) {
            println("$name, sleep!")
        } else {
            println("$name, let's play!")
        }
    }
}

fun main() {

    val gippy = Cat("Gippy")

    gippy.toSleep()
    gippy.sleep = true
    gippy.toSleep()
}
```

The results:

```
Gippy, let's play!
Gippy, sleep!
```

Expecting result supposed to be like this:

```
Function getter is called
Gippy, let's play!
Function setter is called
Function getter is called
Gippy, sleep!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined getter and setter incorrectly. It should be:

```
var sleep: Boolean = false
    get() {
        println("Function getter is called")
        return field
    }
    set(value) {
        field = value
        println("Function setter is called")
    }
```

where `field` - is a [Backing Field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields). From the docs:

> Fields cannot be declared directly in Kotlin classes. However, when a
>   property needs a backing field, Kotlin provides it automatically. This
>   backing field can be referenced in the accessors using the `field`
>   identifier.

[Here is more info about getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters).

Comment: Could you please add to the bottom of your question edited `Cat` class.

Comment: Also please pay attention getter and setter are used without `fun` keyword and `=` sign.